# Excel VBA: Copying Formula to any active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA coding and hope I can get some assistance here. I am trying to create code that would do the following for ANY cell (without specifying hard coded cell ranges or references):

- input a formula in the active cell
- copy it (fill) down 10 rows

In an attempt to insert the formula into the **ActiveCell** I tried:

```
Sub Test()
ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(C5)*ISBLANK(D5),"",IF(ISBLANK(D5),(C5),CONCATENATE(C5,"" ["", D5, ""]"")))"
End Sub
```

However, this produces the 
**1004: Application-define or object-defined error**

I've tried declaring **Range** objects for **ActiveCell** but still run into errors.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(C5)*ISBLANK(D5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(D5),(C5),CONCATENATE(C5,"" ["", D5, ""]"")))"
```

you missed doubling up the first set of embedded quotes.

Comment: @Adeel - And consider `ActiveCell.Resize(10, 1).Formula` rather than just `ActiveCell.Formula`

Comment: awesome this helped. one line of code to tackle it all, lol. exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you. Your keen eye on the missing quotes helped immensely too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following routine to copy formula from cell to VBE compatible format. See if it helps you:

```
 Public Sub CopyExcelFormulaInVBAFormat()
 Dim strFormula As String
 Dim objDataObj As Object

 '\Check that single cell is selected!
 If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
     MsgBox "Select single cell only!", vbCritical
     Exit Sub
 End If

 'Check if we are not on a blank cell!
 If Len(ActiveCell.Formula) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No Formula To Copy!", vbCritical
     Exit Sub
 End If

 'Add quotes as required in VBE
 strFormula = Chr(34) & Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34)

 'This is ClsID of MSFORMS Data Object
 Set objDataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
 objDataObj.SetText strFormula, 1
 objDataObj.PutInClipboard
 MsgBox "VBA Format formula copied to Clipboard!", vbInformation

 Set objDataObj = Nothing

 End Sub
```

After inserting this routine. You just need to enter the formula normally in the cell. Then stay on the cell and run this code and it will copy to clipboard. Go to VBE and do CTRL+V to paste the code where required.

Originally posted on:

https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/copy-formula-from-excel-to-clipboard-in-vba-compatible-format.35997/

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your input but this is sort of reverse of what I am looking to do. Perhaps I should expand on my original request: I am trying to keep it simple to a shortcut key. Let's says Ctrl+Shift+R would automatically copy the formula (provided in original question) to **ANY** active cell and then fill it 10 rows below. 

Any ideas on that?